# Local PostgreSQL refusing connection with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, macos, postgresql, jdbc, intellij-idea

A week ago I installed PostgreSQL with Homebrew following [this tutorial](http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/). Everything worked fined and I was perfectly able to connect to the database in my Java Example Project. Two days ago, I've tried to see the code again and Java is throwing the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:239)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:127)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:41)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:414)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:282)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:61)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:121)
    ... 16 more
```

At the beginning I've thought postgresql just stopped listening the port, but it is listening:

```
$ lsof -i :5432
COMMAND    PID      USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
postgres 39225 barbarity    5u  IPv6 0x4ef6e84c8de72f23      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres 39225 barbarity    6u  IPv4 0x4ef6e84ca3a79493      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
```

And also I can connect from both PGAdmin and PSQL:

```
$ psql -d prakt -U barbarity
psql (9.4.2)
Type "help" for help.

prakt=#
```

Then I tried to uninstall and reinstall from homebrew, but it didn't work neither. I've also tried Postgress.app and nothing also.

Do you have any ideas?

I'm using:

- Java SDK 1.8
- JDBC 41
- PostgreSQL 9.4.2
- IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3

(I put the java code just in case, but it was working a week ago)

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String query = new StringBuilder()
                .append("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id_customer = ? or f_name = ?").toString();

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql:prakt", "barbarity", "");
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);){

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1);
            preparedStatement.setString(2,"Richard");

            try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();){
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    System.out.println(new StringBuilder()
                            .append("Name: ")
                            .append(resultSet.getString(2))
                            .toString());
                }
                resultSet.close();

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to configure the [pg-hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file to allow TCP/IP access

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't do it the first time. It's local, not a external host. By default pg-hba has local   all             all                                     trust

Comment: When you connect on command line, try using `-h localhost`, because omitting this it uses unix sockets by default and that's not a TCP connection like your Java uses.

Comment: @RealSkeptic works with `-h localhost` and `-h 127.0.0.1`

Comment: OK, then are you sure you are not running this Java connection on any other machine, such as a virtual machine (VMWare, Parallels, etc.)?

Comment: No, I've created a project in IntelliJ IDEA on my `$HOME` folder. I've tried with Eclipse and Eclipse doesn't work neither...

Comment: How about directly from command line?

Comment: try to change the connection url jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/prakt

Comment: @RealSkeptic sorry I don't know how to do it from command line. But i've just noticed the path of Java is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk...` Maybe it is a Virtual Machine?

Comment: @Milkmaid didn't work either...

Comment: @RealSkeptic I think I found the solution. The problem is Java is connecting through my local network address (`192.168...`). Now it works but i don't understand why java changed its behaviour from one day to another